# In Pytest, cannot find global variable defined in fixture

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have following file called functions.py:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='function', autouse=True)
def create_driver():
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

And I have following test case file:

```py
from functions import *

def test_google_search(create_driver):
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='q']").send_keys("hello test")
```

It gives error that not find variable "driver":

> NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like abuse of the pytest [fixtures functionality](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/fixtures.html). There should be no need for global variables.

I didn't test it, but something along these lines is how fixtures are supposed to be used:

**my_fixtures.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest

@pytest.fixture  # No need for autouse, and scope='function' is the default
def driver():  # Must match the name of the argument of the test function
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    yield driver  # Yield the driver object to the test case
    driver.quit()
```

Test case:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import my_fixtures  # Makes the fixture available to pytest

def test_google_search(driver):  # Must match the name of the fixture
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='q']").send_keys("hello test")
```

Comment: E       fixture 'driver' not found
>       available fixtures: _pytest_bdd_example, cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, extra, include_metadata_in_junit_xml, metadata, monkeypatch, pytestbdd_given_trace, pytestbdd_then_trace, pytestbdd_when_trace, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

Comment: When I moved fixture to conftest.py file, it works(no need to import it). But, in that case, is there any way to use driver object globally i.e insted of "test_google_search(driver)" use  test_google_search() ?

Comment: Probably, but why would you? [The Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/) says: "Explicit is better than implicit."